# Is execution stopped after an error?

Tags: bash

When running a shell script, suppose an error occurs at one line. Are the other lines executed or does the execution of the script stop? I have a script I want to execute with many commands over the week end and I want to make sure if an error occurs at a line, the other lines are executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execution continues regardless of errors within commands (exit status isn't 0) unless you explicitly specify to stop execution in the event of an error (`set -e`). However, in the case of a syntax error, execution stops.

As a general note, if the subsequent commands depend on any of the previous commands being run correctly, then those won't work correctly.

Example ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately
```

Comment: That is not entirely true, it depend on the type of error. Syntax errors will stop execution for example.

Comment: I agree, in general scripts are going to exit with an error code, depends on the syntax and type of error.

Comment: My bad; I had an incorrect example in my mind. Answer edited.

Comment: Where do I `set -e`?

Comment: `set -e` will apply to all commands you run after that command (unless you unset it). Therefore, you may want to have it at the top of your script file.